# AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp Unprotect ticket failed in IIS child app

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a basic AspnetCore 8 app using Microsoft Identity Azure login that perfectly works when hosted as a site in IIS, but that fails with the error "Unprotect ticket failed" when hosted in a child application:

- root webapp (AspNetCore 7)
  -- child app (AspNetCore 8) /childapp

The child app is configured properly with its own Application pool, and as said works perfectly if published at the root of an IIS site.
When published as a child, I see Azure authentication is successfull, but then the "Unprotect ticket failed" error comes out and a loop starts between the app and login.microsoft.com.

Can anybody tell how to solve?

The app also handles an API key authorization handler for some webapi methods, but the default scheme to login to pages is OpenIdConnect - here's part of my code:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddJwtBearer()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(
    options =>
    {
        builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);

        options.Events.OnTokenValidated = (context) =>
        {
            // removed code to get the user from the database
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };


        options.Events.OnTicketReceived = context =>
        {
            if (context.Principal == null) return Task.CompletedTask;

            // removed code to set claims
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };

    })
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
            .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;

    string? skey = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ApiKey");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(skey)) { skey = "1234567890"; }

    options.AddPolicy("ApiKeyPolicy",
            policyBuilder => policyBuilder
                .AddRequirements(new ApiKeyRequirement(new[] { skey }))
                .AddAuthenticationSchemes(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAuthenticationSchemes(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .Build());
});
```

Here's the log:

```
2023-12-13 11:06:43.6726 WARN Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition False MSAL 4.57.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.0 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045 [2023-12-13 10:06:43Z - f7e548fd-28f2-4656-a9cb-c8c1a8ebd229] Only in-memory caching is used. The cache is not persisted and will be lost if the machine is restarted. It also does not scale for a web app or web API, where the number of users can grow large. In production, web apps and web APIs should use distributed caching like Redis. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-cca-token-cache-serialization
2023-12-13 11:06:43.6726 INFO Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition False MSAL 4.57.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.0 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045 [2023-12-13 10:06:43Z - f7e548fd-28f2-4656-a9cb-c8c1a8ebd229] [Instance Discovery] Instance discovery is enabled and will be performed
2023-12-13 11:06:43.6726 INFO Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition False MSAL 4.57.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.0 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045 [2023-12-13 10:06:43Z - f7e548fd-28f2-4656-a9cb-c8c1a8ebd229] [Region discovery] Not using a regional authority. 
2023-12-13 11:06:43.8142 INFO Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition False MSAL 4.57.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.0 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045 [2023-12-13 10:06:43Z - f7e548fd-28f2-4656-a9cb-c8c1a8ebd229] Checking client info returned from the server..
2023-12-13 11:06:43.8142 INFO Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition False MSAL 4.57.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.0 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045 [2023-12-13 10:06:43Z - f7e548fd-28f2-4656-a9cb-c8c1a8ebd229] Saving token response to cache..
2023-12-13 11:06:43.8142 INFO Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition False MSAL 4.57.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.0 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045 [2023-12-13 10:06:43Z - f7e548fd-28f2-4656-a9cb-c8c1a8ebd229] [Region discovery] Not using a regional authority. 
2023-12-13 11:06:43.8142 INFO Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition False MSAL 4.57.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.0 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045 [2023-12-13 10:06:43Z - f7e548fd-28f2-4656-a9cb-c8c1a8ebd229] [SaveTokenResponseAsync] Saving AT in cache and removing overlapping ATs...
2023-12-13 11:06:43.8142 INFO Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition False MSAL 4.57.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.0 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045 [2023-12-13 10:06:43Z - f7e548fd-28f2-4656-a9cb-c8c1a8ebd229] Looking for scopes for the authority in the cache which intersect with user.read
2023-12-13 11:06:43.8142 INFO Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition False MSAL 4.57.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.0 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045 [2023-12-13 10:06:43Z] [Internal cache] Total number of cache partitions found while getting access tokens: 1
2023-12-13 11:06:43.8142 INFO Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition False MSAL 4.57.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.0 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045 [2023-12-13 10:06:43Z - f7e548fd-28f2-4656-a9cb-c8c1a8ebd229] Intersecting scope entries count - 1
2023-12-13 11:06:43.8142 INFO Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition False MSAL 4.57.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.0 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045 [2023-12-13 10:06:43Z - f7e548fd-28f2-4656-a9cb-c8c1a8ebd229] Matching entries after filtering by user - 1
2023-12-13 11:06:43.8142 INFO Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition False MSAL 4.57.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.0 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045 [2023-12-13 10:06:43Z - f7e548fd-28f2-4656-a9cb-c8c1a8ebd229] [SaveTokenResponseAsync] Saving Id Token and Account in cache ...
2023-12-13 11:06:43.8142 INFO Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition False MSAL 4.57.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.0 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045 [2023-12-13 10:06:43Z - f7e548fd-28f2-4656-a9cb-c8c1a8ebd229] [SaveTokenResponseAsync] Saving RT in cache...
2023-12-13 11:06:43.8142 INFO Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition False MSAL 4.57.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.0 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045 [2023-12-13 10:06:43Z - f7e548fd-28f2-4656-a9cb-c8c1a8ebd229] 
    === Token Acquisition finished successfully:
2023-12-13 11:06:43.8142 INFO Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition False MSAL 4.57.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.0 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045 [2023-12-13 10:06:43Z - f7e548fd-28f2-4656-a9cb-c8c1a8ebd229]  AT expiration time: 13/12/2023 11:17:00 +00:00, scopes: Mail.Send User.Read profile openid email. source: IdentityProvider
2023-12-13 11:06:43.8142 INFO Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition False MSAL 4.57.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.0 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045 [2023-12-13 10:06:43Z - f7e548fd-28f2-4656-a9cb-c8c1a8ebd229] Fetched access token from host login.microsoftonline.com. 
2023-12-13 11:06:43.8142 INFO Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition False MSAL 4.57.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.0 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045 [2023-12-13 10:06:43Z - f7e548fd-28f2-4656-a9cb-c8c1a8ebd229] 
[LogMetricsFromAuthResult] Cache Refresh Reason: NotApplicable
[LogMetricsFromAuthResult] DurationInCacheInMs: 0
[LogMetricsFromAuthResult] DurationTotalInMs: 141
[LogMetricsFromAuthResult] DurationInHttpInMs: 139

2023-12-13 11:06:43.8142 INFO Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition False MSAL 4.57.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.0 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045 [2023-12-13 10:06:43Z - f7e548fd-28f2-4656-a9cb-c8c1a8ebd229] TokenEndpoint: ****
2023-12-13 11:06:43.8142 INFO Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter IDX10242: Security token: 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IlQxU3QtZExUdnlXUmd4Ql82NzZ1OGtyWFMtSSJ9.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.VXPh92y-bbx51xoO0Aj6LimqvsTuBbqlZ79ZsEGfGM2Ft03nuh-e5fTB7Le6B3ZtsJGLfIgue1BT0MDaYVMHmDdhAnuWCLIRKV_umwtInd1WPdO-7yJTS79wpN5j5XameooHhQ3GRXKuh8Ax5BqZmKkte6XCERX5OPOa-PlhBdTBGFC4LyEuhXZa0MXpwsYx0QDTZzb8hOlixTO9yjj6QVgWU9ALdUO_jvSA4LLxU4RjXyhtX6sEr4teeIoIpauSz3F2F2cG5OipYOLtwFURqntrl64vYBx7THK6qw4zixNlPweB26ALmYbIGDQT3wOw_3APcjFZz9b4sYGG_LeHDQ' has a valid signature.
2023-12-13 11:06:43.8142 INFO Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter IDX10239: Lifetime of the token is valid.
2023-12-13 11:06:43.8142 INFO Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter IDX10234: Audience Validated.Audience: '7396d7f6-6c60-46f0-b052-2eb67b0ce531'
2023-12-13 11:06:43.8142 INFO Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter IDX10245: Creating claims identity from the validated token: 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IlQxU3QtZExUdnlXUmd4Ql82NzZ1OGtyWFMtSSJ9.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.VXPh92y-bbx51xoO0Aj6LimqvsTuBbqlZ79ZsEGfGM2Ft03nuh-e5fTB7Le6B3ZtsJGLfIgue1BT0MDaYVMHmDdhAnuWCLIRKV_umwtInd1WPdO-7yJTS79wpN5j5XameooHhQ3GRXKuh8Ax5BqZmKkte6XCERX5OPOa-PlhBdTBGFC4LyEuhXZa0MXpwsYx0QDTZzb8hOlixTO9yjj6QVgWU9ALdUO_jvSA4LLxU4RjXyhtX6sEr4teeIoIpauSz3F2F2cG5OipYOLtwFURqntrl64vYBx7THK6qw4zixNlPweB26ALmYbIGDQT3wOw_3APcjFZz9b4sYGG_LeHDQ'.
2023-12-13 11:06:43.8214 INFO Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler AuthenticationScheme: Cookies signed in.
2023-12-13 11:06:43.8214 INFO Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST https://myhost/childapp/signin-oidc - 302 - - 149.6909ms
2023-12-13 11:06:44.1641 INFO Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://myhost/childapp - - -
2023-12-13 11:06:44.1641 INFO Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler Cookies was not authenticated. Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed
2023-12-13 11:06:44.1641 INFO Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler OpenIdConnect was not authenticated. Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed
2023-12-13 11:06:44.1641 INFO Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
2023-12-13 11:06:44.1641 INFO Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler AuthenticationScheme: OpenIdConnect was challenged.
2023-12-13 11:06:44.1641 INFO Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET https://myhost/childapp - 302 - - 4.0914ms
```

I thought about changing the cookie name and path and adding a basepath, but was unable to solve.

Comment: According to your scenario the most common issue usually happends in applciation path. But as you already tried changing path. So please double-check that both the parent and child applications are using the same encryption key. This can be verified by comparing the values of the DataProtectionProvider properties in both applications.
If you haven't explicitly configured the data protection provider, make sure the applications are running on the same machine or using a shared file system to access the encryption keys.

Comment: Also make sure that, the cookies issued by the parent app have the correct issuer and audience claims. These claims should match the values configured in the child app for cookie validation. You can use a browser developer tool like Fiddler to inspect the cookies and verify the issuer and audience claims.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I ended up calling .configureCookieAuthenticationOptions() and setting the cookie to samesite with this: c.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;